# Xcode 7.3 visual editor not appearing for .xcodeproj and .xcdatamodeld

Tags: ios, xcode7.3

I have recently upgraded to Xcode 7.3 and after some time my .xcodeproj and .xcdatamodeld file are no more appearing in visual editors. I have tried to restart the project as well, but it still shows the files in text format.

**.xcodeproj**
[image]

**.xcdatamodeld**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to restart XCode and my MAC but it didn't fixed the problem.

Then I Closed the XCode and installed my pods again with `$pod install` command and opened my project. After 10-15 seconds of indexing by XCode, visual editor was back for `.xcodeproj` and `.xcdatamodeld`.

It looks that due to some issues or previous pod update project's internal files were in in-consistent state and rebuilding and updating pods fixed the issue.

**Update:**

This issue will occur if you have 'version editor' option selected in Xcode's top right corner.
[image: XCode's Version Editor option]